# jigsaw-engine splicer for linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, game, debian

Does anybody know of good jigsaw splicer for Linux? I know but don't remember a tool which did that, you could tell it how many pieces you wanted the jigsaw to be and other things. Don't remember where I saw it, either in Debian or elsewhere. It is an active project. What I am looking for is something similar to https://github.com/Neon22/inkscape-jigsaw but is more a self-tool whereas this one is an add-on for Inkscape and has multiple ways in which you could make a jigsaw. If anybody knows of the tool I'm talking about or similar tools please share here. Not looking for CLI tools but GUI-based ones.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for palapeli, found it hence closing my own question. Palapeli is in the KDE games section. See [Palapeli - Jigsaw puzzle game](https://www.kde.org/applications/games/palapeli/). It is the only jigsaw game I have seen in FOSS which comes with it own number of slicers and everything. There is even a tutorial as to how you can go on making your own slicer if you want to.

[Development/Tutorials/Games/Palapeli Slicers](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Games/Palapeli_Slicers)

I am/was looking for a game and game-engine which is active and that is what I found and it is open-source. I hope I have been able to explain the reasoning for the same.